# USB drive not working after burning ISO

Tags: usb, flashing

I burned a ubuntu 20.04 iso on my 16 gig flash drive using rufus, installing worked fine (on another computer) but when i plugged it into my windows machine, it did not detect the drive anywhere.[photo from disk managment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DgrZE.png) and [photo from explorer.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v57bH.png)
I cant even boot from it anymore. [Photo from error after trying to boot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBegg.jpg)
before burning the iso, it worked fine but it stopped. I had the same problem on my old usb with exactly the same problem after flashing ubuntu but i do not know what i did to fix the old one.

I plugged the usb drive into 3 laptops:

-my main windows laptop ("no media")

-my aunties laptop where she wanted linux (worked here)

-my old laptop witch is now my brothers (the laptop from the photo trying to boot)

Comment: on Tuesday ill go to my auntie to test the drive on their ubuntu and if it detects it, ill try to format it

Comment: Try a disk-partitioning tool, such as diskmgmt.msc or Disk Genius.

Comment: I tried it on my kali live machine and gparted does not detect it

Comment: If another tool does not work, then it is damaged beyond repair. Removing without unmounting can do that.

Comment: i did not remove it without unmounting, i tried checking the drives on linux (with gparted) and did not detect either.

Comment: i dont know whats the problem but i was flashing kali linux, 2 usb drives had a problem when used the DD mode but with the ISO mode, it still workes